# gazebo_ros_control plugin causes all joints and links to collapse to the origin of gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-noetic, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-11

I'm currently trying to simulate a 6 wheeled differential drive robot in gazebo with ros noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. However, I'm running into an issue when I launch my robot into gazebo, the robot does not spawn properly when gazebo_ros_control is loaded. In particular, all the joints and links collapse to the origin in gazebo. Despite this, RViz generally shows the robot correctly (where the joints and links are not collapsing to the origin), but i only run into the error that there is `No transform from [world] to [base_link]`

However, I do see that the robot temporarily spawns correctly, but it only "breaks" when gazebo_ros_control is loaded. Further testing this, I commented out the gazebo_ros_control plugin in my urdf, and evidently the robot spawns correctly, but obviously I can't use ros_control as intended.The first picture shows when the plugin is loaded and the second shows when the plugin is commented out:

[image: robot in gazebo when gazebo_ros_control plugin is loaded]

[image: robot in gazebo when gazebo_ros_control plugin not loaded]

My package structure appears as follows:

```
grizzly_gazebo
-config
--control.yaml
--pid_gains.yaml
-launch
--grizzly_control.launch
--grizzly_description.launch
--grizzly_gazebo.launch
-urdf
--grizzly.gazebo.xacro
--grizzly.urdf.xacro
--materials.xacro
-CMakeLists.txt
-package.xml
```

To launch my robot into gazebo, I enter the following lines into different terminals:

- `roslaunch grizzly_gazebo grizzly_gazebo.launch`
- `roslaunch grizzly_gazebo grizzly_description.launch`
- `roslaunch grizzly_gazebo grizzly_control.launch`

Here are the relevant launch files:

- grizzly_gazebo.launch:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="world_file" default="$(find grizzly_gazebo)/worlds/grizzly_world.world"/>
  
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_file)"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

- grizzly_description.launch

```
<launch>

  <!-- Load the robot description parameter -->
  <param name="/robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find grizzly_gazebo)/urdf/grizzly.urdf.xacro'"/>
  
  <!-- static transform from the base_link to a sensor frame -->
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="sensor_broadcaster" args="0 0 1 0 0 0 base_link sensor_frame" />

  <!-- Load pid gains from the pid_gains.yaml file -->
  <rosparam file="$(find grizzly_gazebo)/config/pid_gains.yaml" command="load"/>

  <!-- Spawn the robot in Gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model grizzly -x 0 -y 0 -z 0.130" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
  

</launch>
```

- grizzly_control.launch:

```
<launch>

    <!-- Load the joint state controller and differential drive controller configurations from the control.yaml file -->
    <rosparam file="$(find grizzly_gazebo)/config/control.yaml" command="load"/>

    <!-- Spawn the controllers -->
    <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen"
          args="controllers/joint_state_controller controllers/diff_drive_controller"/>
    
    <!-- Use the robot_state_publisher to publish the robot states -->
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
    
</launch>
```

Here are the relevant config files:

- control.yaml:

```
controllers:
# Define the joint state controller
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 20

# Differential drive controller configuration
  diff_drive_controller:
    type: "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
    
    left_wheel: ['wheel_fl_joint', 'wheel_ml_joint', 'wheel_rl_joint']
    right_wheel: ['wheel_fr_joint', 'wheel_mr_joint', 'wheel_rr_joint']
    
    wheel_separation: 0.6875
    wheel_radius: 0.125

    pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    
    publish_rate: 20
    cmd_vel_timeout: 0.5
    
    enable_odom_tf: true
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
     
    linear:
      x:
        has_velocity_limits: true
        max_velocity: 1.0
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration: 0.5
    angular:
      z:
        has_velocity_limits: true
        max_velocity: 2.0
        has_acceleration_limits: true
        max_acceleration: 1.0
```

- pid_gains.yaml:

```
gazebo_ros_control:
  pid_gains:
    wheel_fl_joint:
      p: 2.0
      i: 0.01
      d: 0.1
      i_clamp: 2.0
    wheel_ml_joint:
      p: 2.0
      i: 0.01
      d: 0.1
      i_clamp: 2.0
    wheel_rl_joint:
      p: 2.0
      i: 0.01
      d: 0.1
      i_clamp: 2.0
    wheel_fr_joint:
      p: 2.0
      i: 0.01
      d: 0.1
      i_clamp: 2.0
    wheel_mr_joint:
      p: 2.0
      i: 0.01
      d: 0.1
      i_clamp: 2.0
    wheel_rr_joint:
      p: 2.0
      i: 0.01
      d: 0.1
      i_clamp: 2.0
```

Here are the relevant urdf files:

- grizzly.gazebo.xacro:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotSimType>gazebo_ros_control/DefaultRobotHWSim</robotSimType>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

</robot>
```

- grizzly.urdf.xacro:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="grizzly">

 <!-- Include the Gazebo-specific xacro file -->
 <xacro:include filename="$(find grizzly_gazebo)/urdf/grizzly.gazebo.xacro"/>
 <xacro:include filename="$(find grizzly_gazebo)/urdf/materials.xacro"/>

 <!-- constants -->
 <xacro:property name="deg_to_rad" value="0.017453"/>
 <xacro:property name="pi" value="3.141592653589793"/>

 <!-- wheel and chassis properties -->
 <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.125"/>
 <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.0625"/>
 <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="0.2"/>
 <xacro:property name="chassis_length" value="1.0"/>
 <xacro:property name="chassis_width" value="0.625"/>
 <xacro:property name="chassis_height" value="0.25"/>
 <xacro:property name="chassis_mass" value="10.0"/>
 
 <!-- cylinder macro for wheels -->
 <xacro:macro name="cylinder_inertia" params ="m r h">
  <inertial>
   <mass value="${m}"/>
   <inertia ixx="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}"  ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
            iyy="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}"  iyz= "0.0"
        izz="${m*r*r/2}"/>
   <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
   </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <!-- box macro for chassis -->
  <xacro:macro name="box_inertia" params="mass x y z">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${mass}"/>
  <inertia ixx="${(1/12)*mass*(y*y+z*z)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
      iyy="${(1/12)*mass*(x*x+z*z)}" iyz="0.0"
  izz="${(1/12)*mass*(x*x+y*y)}"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>


 <!-- Base link -->
 <link name="world"></link>

 <!-- Chassis -->
 <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
  <parent link="world"/>
  <child link="base_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.125"/>
 </joint>

 <link name="base_link">
   <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
     <geometry>
       <box size="${chassis_length} ${chassis_width} ${chassis_height}"/>
 </geometry>
 <material name="brown"/>
   </visual>
   <collision>
 <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
 <geometry>
   <box size="${chassis_length} ${chassis_width} ${chassis_height}"/>
     </geometry>
   </collision>
   <xacro:box_inertia mass="${chassis_mass}" x="${chassis_length}" y="${chassis_width}" z="${chassis_height}"/>
 </link>

<gazebo reference="base_link">
  <material>Gazebo/Brown</material> <!-- Gazebo-specific color -->
</gazebo>

 <!-- ////////// WHEELS ////////// -->
 <!-- Front Left Wheel -->
 <joint name="wheel_fl_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="wheel_fl_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0.3125 ${chassis_width/2+0.03125} -0.125" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
 </joint>

 <link name="wheel_fl_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
 </link>

 <transmission name="wheel_fl_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_fl_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="wheel_fl_motor">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>
 
 <gazebo reference="wheel_fl_link">
  <material>Gazebo/Black</material> <!-- Gazebo-specific color -->
 </gazebo>


 <!-- Mid Left Wheel -->
 <joint name="wheel_ml_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="wheel_ml_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0 ${chassis_width/2+0.03125} -0.125" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
 </joint>

 <link name="wheel_ml_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
 </link>

 <transmission name="wheel_ml_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_ml_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="wheel_ml_motor">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>

 <gazebo reference="wheel_ml_link">
  <material>Gazebo/Black</material> <!-- Gazebo-specific color -->
 </gazebo>

 <!-- Rear Left Wheel -->
 <joint name="wheel_rl_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="wheel_rl_link"/>
  <origin xyz="-0.3125 ${chassis_width/2+0.03125} -0.125" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
 </joint>

 <link name="wheel_rl_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
 </link>

 <transmission name="wheel_rl_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_rl_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="wheel_rl_motor">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>

 <gazebo reference="wheel_rl_link">
  <material>Gazebo/Black</material> <!-- Gazebo-specific color -->
 </gazebo>

 <!-- Front Right Wheel -->
 <joint name="wheel_fr_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="wheel_fr_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0.3125 ${-chassis_width/2-0.03125} -0.125" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
 </joint>

 <link name="wheel_fr_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
 </link>

 <transmission name="wheel_fr_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_fr_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="wheel_fr_motor">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>

 <gazebo reference="wheel_fr_link">
  <material>Gazebo/Black</material> <!-- Gazebo-specific color -->
 </gazebo>

 <!-- Mid Right Wheel -->
 <joint name="wheel_mr_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="wheel_mr_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0 ${-chassis_width/2-0.03125} -0.125" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
 </joint>

 <link name="wheel_mr_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
 </link>

 <transmission name="wheel_mr_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_mr_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="wheel_mr_motor">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>

 <gazebo reference="wheel_mr_link">
  <material>Gazebo/Black</material> <!-- Gazebo-specific color -->
 </gazebo>

 <!-- Rear Right Wheel -->
 <joint name="wheel_rr_joint" type="continuous">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="wheel_rr_link"/>
  <origin xyz="-0.3125 ${-chassis_width/2-0.03125} -0.125" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
  <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.7"/>
 </joint>

 <link name="wheel_rr_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:cylinder_inertia m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}"/>
 </link>

 <transmission name="wheel_rr_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="wheel_rr_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
  </joint>
  <actuator name="wheel_rr_motor">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
 </transmission>

 <gazebo reference="wheel_rr_link">
  <material>Gazebo/Black</material> <!-- Gazebo-specific color -->
 </gazebo>

</robot>
```

- materials.xacro:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <material name="black">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>

  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.0 0.8 1.0"/>
  </material>

  <material name="green">
    <color rgba="0.0 0.8 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>

  <material name="grey">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0.2 1.0"/>
  </material>

  <material name="orange">
    <color rgba="${255/255} ${108/255} ${10/255} 1.0"/>
  </material>

  <material name="brown">
    <color rgba="${222/255} ${207/255} ${195/255} 1.0"/>
  </material>

  <material name="red">
    <color rgba="0.8 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
  </material>

  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0"/>
  </material>

</robot>
```

Please let me know if you have ideas! Thank you!